# php date format for mysql query

Tags: php

I can't seem to find this answer.

what would be the php code for having date in this following format:
2012-11-29

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->format('F j, Y');
```

This give me in November 29, 2012

Comment: The format used by DateTime is [documented here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: was it really so hard to look in the manual? or search here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=format+date+php, or google

Comment: even if i look at them, i dont understand them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php